# Is it true that if $V(\mathfrak a)$ is irreducible, then $\mathfrak a$ is prime ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Is it true that if $V(\mathfrak a)$ is irreducible, then $\mathfrak a$ is prime ideal?

I know that if $V$ is an irreducible affine algebraic set if and only if $I(V)$ is a prime ideal. Can I use this result?

Comment: $V(a)$ is the set of zeros of ideal $a$, and I am working in a polynomial ring $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ with coefficients in a field $K$

Comment: Never forget the Nullstellensatz!

Answer (score 6):

Take $\mathfrak a=(X^2,XY)$ in $\mathbb C[X,Y]$. Then $V(\mathfrak a)$ is irreducible iff $I(V(\mathfrak a))$ is a prime ideal. But $I(V(\mathfrak a))=\sqrt{\mathfrak a}=(X)$, hence $V(\mathfrak a)$ is irreducible. But $\mathfrak a$ is not a prime ideal, so the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try to find a reducible polynomial $f \in K[X]$, which vanishes only at one point of $K$ (these polynomials exist). What does this tell you?